# Hostname not registered in the namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I have set Kuberbetes cluster via Rancher. All looks fine till I have decided to deploy Helm Chart app to it (bitnami/wordpress).

Pods and services in the `wordpress` namespace:

```
> kubectl get pods,svc -owide --namespace=wordpress
    NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE    IP           NODE            NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
    pod/wordpress-6647794f9b-4mmxd   0/1     Running   20         104m   10.42.0.19   dev-app   <none>           <none>
    pod/wordpress-mariadb-0          1/1     Running   1          26h    10.42.0.14   dev-app   <none>           <none>
    
    NAME                        TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE   SELECTOR
    service/wordpress           LoadBalancer   10.43.91.13     <pending>     80:30158/TCP,443:30453/TCP   26h   app.kubernetes.io/instance=wordpress,app.kubernetes.io/name=wordpress,io.cattle.field/appId=wordpress
    service/wordpress-mariadb   ClusterIP      10.43.178.123   <none>        3306/TCP                     26h   app=mariadb,component=master,io.cattle.field/appId=wordpress,release=wordpress
```

Then I have tried to verify connections from the Wordpress CMS to the MariaDB:

On the MariaDB pod:

```
I have no name!@wordpress-mariadb-0:/$ cat /etc/hosts                                                      
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
10.42.0.14      wordpress-mariadb-0.wordpress-mariadb.wordpress.svc.cluster.local       wordpress-mariadb-0
```

No clue why `-0` was added to the host name but

```
I have no name!@wordpress-mariadb-0:/$ mysql -h wordpress-mariadb-0.wordpress-mariadb.wordpress.svc.cluster.local -u root -p                   
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 48253
Server version: 10.3.22-MariaDB Source distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

works fine from the MariaDB pod.

Than on the Wordpress pod:

```
I have no name!@wordpress-6647794f9b-4mmxd:/$ mysql -h wordpress-mariadb-0.wordpress-mariadb.wordpress.svc.cluster.local -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'wordpress-mariadb-0.wordpress-mariadb.wordpress.svc.cluster.local' (-3)
```

for some reason hostname is not registered for that namespace.

Any clue?

PS

From the wordpress pod:

```
I have no name!@wordpress-6647794f9b-4mmxd:/$ cat /etc/hosts
# Kubernetes-managed hosts file.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
fe00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
fe00::1 ip6-allnodes
fe00::2 ip6-allrouters
10.42.0.19      wordpress-6647794f9b-4mmxd

# Entries added by HostAliases.
127.0.0.1       status.localhost
```

and

```
I have no name!@wordpress-6647794f9b-4mmxd:/$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 10.43.0.10
search wordpress.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
options ndots:5
```

PS2

```
> kubectl get pod -n kube-system
NAME                                      READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
canal-8bf2l                               2/2     Running     0          16d
canal-g782s                               2/2     Running     2          16d
canal-vq474                               2/2     Running     0          16d
coredns-849545576b-gcf7p                  1/1     Running     0          16d
coredns-849545576b-vtqpw                  1/1     Running     0          3d20h
coredns-autoscaler-84bf756579-v594n       1/1     Running     0          3d20h
metrics-server-697746ff48-rtw2h           1/1     Running     1          16d
rke-coredns-addon-deploy-job-2sjlv        0/1     Completed   0          3d20h
rke-ingress-controller-deploy-job-9q4c2   0/1     Completed   0          3d20h
rke-metrics-addon-deploy-job-cv42h        0/1     Completed   0          3d20h
rke-network-plugin-deploy-job-4pddn       0/1     Completed   0          3d20h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason one of the nodes with CoreDNS pod (I had two of them) had a problem with providing data for the `kube-dns` service.

Rebuilding that node solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mariadb is deployed as [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).Each Pod in a StatefulSet derives its hostname from the name of the StatefulSet and the ordinal of the Pod. The pattern for the constructed hostname is `$(statefulset name)-$(ordinal)`. This explains why `-0` in podname and hostname.

Ideally you should be using the [Headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) exposing the mysql statefulset to access mysql from wordpress. Below is an example of service, you don't need to create it because it already exists with name
`wordpress-mariadb`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mariadb
  namespace: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: mysql
  clusterIP: None
```

In wordpress pod running in same namespace use `wordpress-mariadb` to access mariadb

Official guide on [deploying wordpress with mysql](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/mysql-wordpress-persistent-volume/)

Comment: As I have mentioned in the OP I used Helm Chart from Bitnami to deploy it. Also I have tried to reach `wordpress-mariadb` from the wordpress pod and I have the same issue as I have described in the OP except IP access works but not via the hostname. Helm Chart has it set as you have described above.

Comment: Check the `/etc/hosts` and `etc/resolv.conf` file in wordpress pod

Comment: Updated OP with output for both.

Comment: In your cluster if you access any  other service does it work? Is the coredns pods in `kube-system` namespace is running?

Comment: Yes - coreDNS is up and running (updated OP with the listing for the `kube--system`)

Comment: It came up one of the nodes has problems with CoreDNS. In that case should I scrape it or re-register it with the Rancher again and push all images using RKE?